# aws cdk/cloudformation autoscaling dont start instance before lifecycle hook is enabled

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-auto-scaling

I have a cdk project with an autoscaling group and lifecycle hooks.
The lifecycle hooks trigger a lambda via an Event Rule.

When I deploy, the following happens:

1. The ASG gets created => And immidatly starts an instance without lifecycle hooks.
2. The Lifecycle hooks get created (they depend on the ASG).

This means the first instance is created without lifecycle hooks!
That is not acceptable, I may not have running instances that never got "made ready" by the lifecycle hook.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I hit the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Use a level 1 construct (CdkAutoscalingGroup) and define the lifecycle hooks directly in the ash.